# Git-SVN: Update Git repo from centralized SVN server

Tags: git, git-svn, git-pull, git-fetch

I'm working on a project for which everyone uses `SVN` as a centralized server and everybody pushes the changes they do on that server. I want to use `Git` locally and I'm pretty new to `git svn`. I did a `git svn clone` of the repository with `git svn clone -r HEAD https://svn.repo/app/branch` an I want to do an update through git.

I need a 'git pull like' command but to pull from a specific revision of the SVN server repo.
Also is there a 'fetch like' command to fetch from a specific revision of the SVN server repo?

I don't have any `.svn` folders in my cloned project and `git remote` doesn't give me anything. However I did a `git config -l` and I get the SVN server's URL, so somehow I'm linked with the SVN server. I don't know how to fetch or pull though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Best way to work on a Subversion Repository via Git:

1. `git svn init -s https://svn.repo/app/ myrepo` assuming that under https://svn.repo/app/ the repo contains the standard `/trunk`, `branches` and `tags` subdirectories
2. Do a `git svn fetch` in myrepo until no more commits are fetched (may take quite some time and sometimes aborts under Windows).
3. Checkout a specific Subversion branch or trunk via `git checkout -b trunk remotes/trunk`

Then you can simply browse, hack and commit into your Git Repo containing all Subversion commits and branches.

- To pull in new commits from SVN use `git svn rebase`
- To push your local commits into SVN use `git svn dcommit`

To jump to a specific Subversion revision you only need to browse the history via `git log` and search for a commit mirroring the according subversion commit. You can easily spot the Subversion revision in the `git-svn-id:` line of the commit message. The just use a `git checkout <commithash>` to explicitly checkout that version.

Comment: I realize this is an old question/answer, but when I do `git svn rebase` I'm not getting the actual latest from SVN.  It seems that it only sees SVN commits up to the point I did the `git svn clone`.  Even when I do `git svn info` it says the latest change was back on the day I did the clone.

Comment: Hi @mojave. At least `git svn fetch` should contact and fetch new commits from the server. If you rename `.git/svn` this should even refetch the whole history. Did you crosscheck with `svn info <URL>`?

Comment: Thanks, I did end up recloning because I ran out of time to get the job done.  Took 47 hours for the git-svn clone to complete :)

Answer (score 14):

**A good start :**

To fetch new svn commit into your local repo : `git svn rebase`

To push your local commit to SVN : `git svn dcommit`

You will probably have to use `git stash` and `git stash pop`, before using the two commands above when your working copy has uncommited changes.